# Minimum degree of 4-connected toroidal graph

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a 4-connected toroidal graph. Find the minimum degree $\delta(G)$ of $G$. It is known that cross product of two cycle of even length is toroidal graph and also 4-connected. Hence minimum degree of this graph is 4. If we can prove that $\delta(G) = 4$ explicitly without taking an example. Any hint or direction how to prove is appreciable. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, $\delta(G)$ depends on $G$. Indeed, if you add diagonals to your product of even cycles to make all faces triangular, you can achieve $\delta(G)=6$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Then Connectivity of $G$ is 6.